# Generalization of "Lipschitz implies bounded derivatives" for Holder functions

Tags: real-analysis, lipschitz-functions, holder-spaces

Is there a generalization of the following statement for Holder continuous functions:
For $f:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ Lipschitz continuous, $\|\nabla f\|$ is uniformly bounded.

What I am looking for is something along the lines: If $f$ is Holder continous with exponent $\alpha$,
$$\|\nabla f(x)\| \leq C f(x)^{2-2\alpha}.$$

If the above statement was correct (it is not), for $\alpha=1$, we recover the previous statement for the Lipschitz functions.

Comment: It's definitely not true as stated, the sign $f$ can change but $\|\nabla f\|$ is always positive.

Comment: Thanks, updated the statement to make it more clear.